# Nvidia GeForce 9300GT or 9400GS chipset on graphic card

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, nvidia-graphics-card, dell-vostro

Dell Vostro 1520 laptop comes with motherboard P/N 00D46F (U653J) equipped with discrete Nvidia GeForce 9300GT or 9400GS Graphic card. Is it possible replace faulty motherboard that have GeForce 9400GS chipset with MB version equipped with GeForce 9300GT chipset? Is yes, does this replacement requires to change graphic drivers?

Answer (score 1):

In case you have another motherboard lying around with another chip but the same format and size. Then yes, replace it. It would probably not be necessary to install new drivers but recommended.